# Java find URL in string and create HTML link tag

Tags: java, html

in my string i have simply this result:

```
content = "Hello world, visit this link: www.stackoverflow.com";
```

or

```
content = "Hello world, visit this link: http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

or

```
content = "Hello world, visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com";
```

now i want to find url in this string and finaly create html link tag like with this result:

```
HtmlContent = "Hello world, visit this link: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com </a> ";
```

how to get this result?

```
HtmlContent = "Hello world, visit this link: <a href="[http://|www.] stackoverflow.com">[http://|www.]stackoverflow.com </a> ";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
String content = "Hello world, visit this link: www.stackoverflow.com";

    String[] splitted = content.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        if ((splitted[i]).contains("www.")) { // use more statements for
                                                // http:// etc..
            System.out.println(splitted[i]); //just checking the output
            String link = "<a href=\"" + splitted[i] + "\">" + splitted[i] + "</a>";

            System.out.println(link); //just checking the output
        }
    }
```

Use \" in the string to write Quotation marks inside a string.

Answer (score 2):

I would split the sentence into an array, and check if each one has `www` or `http` in it:

```
string[] possibleLinks = content.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < possibleLinks.length; i++)
    if (possibleLinks[i].contains("http://") || possibleLinks[i].contains("www."))
    {
        //Use the link here, which will be posibleLinks[i]
    }
```

Since you actually want to modify the existing string, you could try this:

```
String content = "Hello World! Visit: http://www.lol.com";
int a = 0, b = 0;

a = content.contains("http://") ? content.indexOf("http://") : content.indexOf("www.");
b = content.indexOf(".com") + 4;

if (a != -1)
{
    String link = content.substring(a,b);
    content = content.substring(0,a) + "<a href=\"" + link + "\"/>" + link + "</a>";
}

System.out.println(content);
```

It's not the prettiest code in the world, but I've tested it, and it works.

Comment: i want to create html link tag for `www.sample.com` such as `<a href="www.sample.com"> www.sample.com </a>`. i dont to parse html in string.

Comment: @andbee Alright, I've updated my answer, try that out

Answer (score 2):

Split your `content` string as:

```
String[] tokens = content.split(" ");
```

Loop through `tokens` and use *regex* to identify the token is valid *url*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
    String regex = "^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$";

    // if valid match replace this token with desired string. as in your case:
    if(Pattern.matches(regex, tokens[i])){
        tokens[i] = "<a href='"+tokens[i]+"'>"+tokens[i]+"</a>";
    }
}
```

Then join the tokens

```
StringBuilder sbStr = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0, i = tokens.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0)
        sbStr.append(" ");
    sbStr.append(aArr[i]);
}

System.out.println(sbStr.toString()); // your expected result.
```

Comment: thank sir. i get this error: `Error:(210, 51) java: illegal escape character` for regex value.